How to Retrieve a Product After Successfully Creating a Feed in Amazon Selling Partner API
I have successfully created a product feed using the Amazon Selling Partner API and received a response indicating that the feed was processed without any errors. Here’s an example of the response I received:
{
    "header": {
        "sellerId": "A30XXXXXXXXX",
        "version": "2.0",
        "feedId": "307972020010"
    },
    "summary": {
        "errors": 0,
        "warnings": 0,
        "messagesProcessed": 1,
        "messagesAccepted": 1
    }
}

Additionally, here’s the product data I submitted in the feed:

{
    "header": {
        "sellerId": "A3XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "version": "2.0",
        "issueLocale": "en_US"
    },
    "messages": [
        {
            "messageId": 1,
            "sku": "AKISK_GB_KK",
            "operationType": "UPDATE",
            "productType": "LUGGAGE",
            "requirements": "LISTING",
            "attributes": {
                "model_name": [
                    {
                        "value": "Model XYZ",
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "color": [
                    {
                        "value": "Red",
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "item_type_keyword": [
                    {
                        "value": "luggage"
                    }
                ],
                "material": [
                    {
                        "value": "Polyester"
                    }
                ],
                "model_number": [
                    {
                        "value": "XYZ123",
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "item_package_weight": [
                    {
                        "value": 2.5,
                        "unit": "pounds"
                    }
                ],
                "department": [
                    {
                        "value": "Travel"
                    }
                ],
                "batteries_required": [
                    {
                        "value": "No"
                    }
                ],
                "product_description": [
                    {
                        "value": "This is a high-quality luggage for all your travel needs."
                    }
                ],
                "brand": [
                    {
                        "value": "ekSel",
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "style": [
                    {
                        "value": "Modern"
                    }
                ],
                "externally_assigned_product_identifier": [
                    {
                        "value": "0123456789012"
                    }
                ],
                "country_of_origin": [
                    {
                        "value": "CN"
                    }
                ],
                "bullet_point": [
                    {
                        "value": "Durable and lightweight."
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "Stylish design."
                    }
                ],
                "item_name": [
                    {
                        "value": "Your Item Name"
                    }
                ],
                "condition_type": [
                    {
                        "value": "new_new",
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "number_of_items": [
                    {
                        "value": 10,
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "list_price": [
                    {
                        "currency": "USD",
                        "value": 100
                    }
                ],
                "item_package_dimensions": [
                    {
                        "length": {
                            "unit": "inches",
                            "value": 5.0
                        },
                        "width": {
                            "unit": "inches",
                            "value": 10.0
                        },
                        "height": {
                            "unit": "inches",
                            "value": 20.0
                        },
                        "marketplace_id": "ATVPDKIKX0DER"
                    }
                ],
                "merchant_suggested_asin": [
                    {
                        "value": "OSKEJEOIII"
                    }
                ],
                "supplier_declared_dg_hz_regulation": [
                    {
                        "value": "unknown"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

Now I want to verify that the product has been created successfully and retrieve its details.
My questions are:

What is the best way to retrieve the newly created product after the feed has been processed?
Is there a specific API endpoint or method to use for checking the product's existence and details, given that I do not have the ASIN (Amazon Standard Identification Number) for the new product?
Are there any best practices for ensuring that the product can be successfully retrieved after the feed creation?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated!
